# Loading js file using codeigniter controller refused by chrome to execute script because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, google-chrome, mime-types

My template js file is loaded via loader controller in codeigniter 3.1
Its work fine in my local xampp server. but not work in remote server for chrome browser. only work in mozila firefox in remote server. Chrome Refused to execute script from 'https://xxxxxxxx.com/loadlanguage/all.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

```
public function jsFile($file = null)
{
    $contents = file_get_contents('.' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'application' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'language' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . MY_LANGUAGE_FULL_NAME . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'js' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file);
    if (!$contents) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
        return;
    }
    echo $contents;
}
```

My js file is

```
var lang = { 
added_to_cart:"Added to cart",
error_to_cart:"Problem with shopping cart! Try again!",
no_products:"No products",
confirm_clear_cart:"Are you sure want to delete items in shopping cart?",
cleared_cart:"Your cart is empty",
are_you_sure:"Are you sure?",
yes:"Yes",
no:"No",
clear_all:"Clear",
checkout:"Payment",
remove_from_cart:"Deleted from shopping cart",
enter_valid_email:"Please enter a valid email address",
};
```

js file is accessible by link status 200 but not work in chrome and it works fine in mozila.
pls help to fix it.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QYgL.jpg)